# How to Iterate through a collection of objects in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm unable to figure out how to loop through a collection of objects stored in my localstorage. Basically i'm storing a bunch of items that have been selected and if it's true, I want to send it server side.

Here is an example of the data in my collection `{"6532":null,"6533":true,"6816":true,"7192":true,"8663":null,"8673":null,"23113":true}`

```
 function ValidateRadGridSelections() {
                    alert(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));
                    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));
                    alert(jsonArray);
                    for (var i = 0, len = jsonArray.length; i < len; ++i) {
                        var jsonObj = jsonArray[i];
                        alert(jsonObj);
                        var selected = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

                        if (selected && selected[id]) {
                           //I want to add the item here to a collection that is sent server side.
                            alert(selected[id]);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;

                }
```

Thanks to the comments below I figured it out.

```
 function ValidateRadGridSelections() {
                    alert(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));
                    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));
                    for (var json in jsonArray) {
                        if (jsonArray[json]) {
                            console.log(json, jsonArray[json]);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;

                }
```

Comment: You don't need to do `JSON.parse` again and again. After you first `JSON.parse` the JSON string becomes a javascript object. Then you can handle like that.

Comment: @vibhor1997a I don't follow, how do you iterate the first var jsonArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));  I don't follow

Comment: I think you don't have to `JSON.parse(jsonObj)`. `var selected = jsonObj;` should be fine.